# Deadlock with lock around and inside Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, locking, task-parallel-library, deadlock, parallel.foreach

Can you please explain why this code deadlocks ?

```
int[] testlist = new int[ ] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
lock ( testlock ) {
    Parallel.ForEach( testlist, new ParallelOptions( ) { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 90 }, ( int i ) => {
        Console.WriteLine( "hi there before " + i + " " + Monitor.IsEntered( testlock ) );
        lock ( testlock ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "hi there inner " + i + " " + Monitor.IsEntered( testlock ) );
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "hi there after " + i + " " + Monitor.IsEntered( testlock ) );
    } );
}
```

Of course without the surrounding lock this code do not deadlock.

Edit:

thanks for the explanation. The typical output is:

```
hi there before 3 True
hi there inner 3 True
hi there after 3 True
hi there before 4 True
hi there inner 4 True
hi there after 4 True
hi there before 5 True
hi there inner 5 True
hi there after 5 True
hi there before 6 True
hi there inner 6 True
hi there after 6 True
hi there before 7 True
hi there inner 7 True
hi there after 7 True
hi there before 8 True
hi there inner 8 True
hi there after 8 True
hi there before 9 True
hi there inner 9 True
hi there after 9 True
hi there before 10 True
hi there inner 10 True
hi there after 10 True
```

In fact, typical execution involes two threads on my machine: one is blocked waiting for lock (the "1" one) and another is running other iterations (from 3 to 10, note the linearity of output). The "1" thread waits forever. Now it is clear, thanks !

Comment: Let's say that main thread is thread1. Thread1 takes lock on `testLock`. Every other thread (different thread to thread1!) produced by `Parallel.ForEach` wants also lock on `testLock` but it is still locked by thread1. Thread1 waits for all `Parallel`-threads to complete = deadlock.

Comment: The only way this code could **ever** work is if `Parallel` decided to run all the iterations on the current primary thread (the one calling `Parallel.ForEach`). For all I know it *might* choose to do that if you only have one core... in all other cases: yes, it will deadlock... because you have written a deadlock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't work because you are definitely creating a deadlock here:

The outer `lock(testlock)` locks on `testlock` and then the `Parallel.ForEach` starts processing your `testlist` in multiple threads. Now these threads get to the inner `lock(testlock)`, but as it is still locked by the outer one in its thread it can not lock it again => the outer `lock` does not release until the processing is done, but the processing can not complete until the outer `lock` releases -> deadlock...

You can easily verify this by using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`: Then everything runs in the main thread and the cascaded lock does not deadlock as it can lock again, because it is the same thread.

What are you trying to do - may we can help if you explain?

*NOTE:*
If your system does not have **90!** CPU's it does NOT help the performance to use `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 90` - it is recommended to keep that number smaller or equal to your CPU/Core  count (you can get that via [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx)).

Comment: I set that to 90 just to try and play with differents values (but yeah I'd be nice to have something with 90 cpu :))

Answer (score 3):

You have taken a lock on `testLock` before starting `Parallel.ForEach` (1st lock). Inside of your Parallel.ForEach, you take a lock on the same object. The ForEach uses a different thread at some point other than the one that took the 1st lock. That thread is going to wait until the lock is available, however it will never be available because the 1st lock won't get released until the ForEach is complete.

Since `ForEach` won't exit until all threads are complete, you end up deadlocked.

Comment: I think it is worth to mention, that main thread waits for all threads produced by `Parallel` to complete.

Comment: @pwas That actually isn't entirely accurate. The "main thread" may actually be one of the threads used by `Parallel.ForEach`, so to say that that thread is just sitting around and waiting isn't true, but I think I understand where you are going with that.

Comment: @pwas Ah OK, you said threads *produced by*, so I think I got what you're saying now.